# VBA Excel - Listbox dynamically update with Table

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, listbox

I wish to create a userform where the user can query, edit and delete some information. This information is stored in my table ('Table1'). What I want is to create a dynamic userform that automatically updates the listbox when I modify my table. I am having trouble figuring out how to link the table with the listbox. Could someone help me?

[image]

I tried to declare my table as an ListObjetct and manipulate with listbox, however didn't succeed.

Comment: When asking here it's typically best to show what you already tried.  Even if it didn't work, explain *how* it didn't work (what did it do, or not do, and how was that different from what you wanted/expected?) and folks are much more likely to offer suggestions